# Aumentar desempenho do sql

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2008

Possuo essa função abaixo que executa esse SQL, porém o tempo de execução desse SQL está muito alto teria algum modo de diminuir o tempo de execução ? Na hora de carrega a página demora em torno de 5 segundos para executar a consulta abaixo. Gostaria de diminuir este tempo a algum jeito ?

```
public function ListaPorTipoP($obj){
    $results = array();
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare
    ('select 
        case when exists (select top 1 A.NrPlaca from GTCLogist A
                            where A.DsTpVeiculo = \'Cavalo Truck\'
                            AND (A.NrPlacaCarreta=B.NrPlaca OR A.NrPlacaReboque2=B.NrPlaca)
                            and A.DtBase = B.DtBase)  Then (select top 1 A.NrPlaca from GTCLogist A
                                                            where A.DsTpVeiculo = \'Cavalo Truck\'
                                                            AND (A.NrPlacaCarreta=B.NrPlaca OR A.NrPlacaReboque2=B.NrPlaca)
                                                            and A.DtBase = B.DtBase)
        else null
    end as [DsCavalo], 
    B.ID,
    B.NrPlaca,
        case when exists (select top 1 A.NrPlaca from GTCLogist A
                            where A.DsTpVeiculo = \'Cavalo Truck\'
                            AND (A.NrPlacaCarreta=B.NrPlaca OR A.NrPlacaReboque2=B.NrPlaca)
                            and A.DtBase = B.DtBase)  Then (select top 1 A.DtProg from GTCLogist A
                                                            where A.DsTpVeiculo = \'Cavalo Truck\'
                                                            AND (A.NrPlacaCarreta=B.NrPlaca OR A.NrPlacaReboque2=B.NrPlaca)
                                                            and A.DtBase = B.DtBase)
        else B.DtProg
    end as [DtProg], 
        case when exists (select top 1 A.NrPlaca from GTCLogist A
                            where A.DsTpVeiculo = \'Cavalo Truck\'
                            AND (A.NrPlacaCarreta=B.NrPlaca OR A.NrPlacaReboque2=B.NrPlaca)
                            and A.DtBase = B.DtBase)  Then (select top 1 A.DsMotorista from GTCLogist A
                                                            where A.DsTpVeiculo = \'Cavalo Truck\'
                                                            AND (A.NrPlacaCarreta=B.NrPlaca OR A.NrPlacaReboque2=B.NrPlaca)
                                                            and A.DtBase = B.DtBase)
        else B.DsMotorista
    end as [DsMotorista], 
        case when exists (select top 1 A.NrPlaca from GTCLogist A
                            where A.DsTpVeiculo = \'Cavalo Truck\'
                            AND (A.NrPlacaCarreta=B.NrPlaca OR A.NrPlacaReboque2=B.NrPlaca)
                            and A.DtBase = B.DtBase)  Then (select top 1 A.DtSaida from GTCLogist A
                                                            where A.DsTpVeiculo = \'Cavalo Truck\'
                                                            AND (A.NrPlacaCarreta=B.NrPlaca OR A.NrPlacaReboque2=B.NrPlaca)
                                                            and A.DtBase = B.DtBase)
        else B.DtSaida
    end as [DtSaida], 
        case when exists (select top 1 A.NrPlaca from GTCLogist A
                            where A.DsTpVeiculo = \'Cavalo Truck\'
                            AND (A.NrPlacaCarreta=B.NrPlaca OR A.NrPlacaReboque2=B.NrPlaca)
                            and A.DtBase = B.DtBase)  Then (select top 1 A.HrSaida from GTCLogist A
                                                            where A.DsTpVeiculo = \'Cavalo Truck\'
                                                            AND (A.NrPlacaCarreta=B.NrPlaca OR A.NrPlacaReboque2=B.NrPlaca)
                                                            and A.DtBase = B.DtBase)
        else B.HrSaida
    end as [HrSaida],     
         case when exists (select top 1 A.NrPlaca from GTCLogist A
                            where A.DsTpVeiculo = \'Cavalo Truck\'
                            AND (A.NrPlacaCarreta=B.NrPlaca OR A.NrPlacaReboque2=B.NrPlaca)
                            and A.DtBase = B.DtBase)  Then (select top 1 A.DtChegada from GTCLogist A
                                                            where A.DsTpVeiculo = \'Cavalo Truck\'
                                                            AND (A.NrPlacaCarreta=B.NrPlaca OR A.NrPlacaReboque2=B.NrPlaca)
                                                            and A.DtBase = B.DtBase)
        else B.DtChegada
    end as [DtChegada],      
        case when exists (select top 1 A.NrPlaca from GTCLogist A
                            where A.DsTpVeiculo = \'Cavalo Truck\'
                            AND (A.NrPlacaCarreta=B.NrPlaca OR A.NrPlacaReboque2=B.NrPlaca)
                            and A.DtBase = B.DtBase)  Then (select top 1 A.HrChegada from GTCLogist A
                                                            where A.DsTpVeiculo = \'Cavalo Truck\'
                                                            AND (A.NrPlacaCarreta=B.NrPlaca OR A.NrPlacaReboque2=B.NrPlaca)
                                                            and A.DtBase = B.DtBase)
        else B.HrChegada
    end as [HrChegada], 
        case when exists (select top 1 A.NrPlaca from GTCLogist A
                            where A.DsTpVeiculo = \'Cavalo Truck\'
                            AND (A.NrPlacaCarreta=B.NrPlaca OR A.NrPlacaReboque2=B.NrPlaca)
                            and A.DtBase = B.DtBase)  Then (select top 1 A.DsOrigem from GTCLogist A
                                                            where A.DsTpVeiculo = \'Cavalo Truck\'
                                                            AND (A.NrPlacaCarreta=B.NrPlaca OR A.NrPlacaReboque2=B.NrPlaca)
                                                            and A.DtBase = B.DtBase)
        else B.DsOrigem
    end as [DsOrigem], 
        case when exists (select top 1 A.NrPlaca from GTCLogist A
                            where A.DsTpVeiculo = \'Cavalo Truck\'
                            AND (A.NrPlacaCarreta=B.NrPlaca OR A.NrPlacaReboque2=B.NrPlaca)
                            and A.DtBase = B.DtBase)  Then (select top 1 A.DsDestino from GTCLogist A
                                                            where A.DsTpVeiculo = \'Cavalo Truck\'
                                                            AND (A.NrPlacaCarreta=B.NrPlaca OR A.NrPlacaReboque2=B.NrPlaca)
                                                            and A.DtBase = B.DtBase)
        else B.DsDestino
    end as [DsDestino], 
        case when exists (select top 1 A.NrPlaca from GTCLogist A
                            where A.DsTpVeiculo = \'Cavalo Truck\'
                            AND (A.NrPlacaCarreta=B.NrPlaca OR A.NrPlacaReboque2=B.NrPlaca)
                            and A.DtBase = B.DtBase)  Then (select top 1 A.DsAgendas from GTCLogist A
                                                            where A.DsTpVeiculo = \'Cavalo Truck\'
                                                            AND (A.NrPlacaCarreta=B.NrPlaca OR A.NrPlacaReboque2=B.NrPlaca)
                                                            and A.DtBase = B.DtBase)
        else B.DsAgendas
    end as [DsAgendas], 
        case when exists (select top 1 A.NrPlaca from GTCLogist A
                            where A.DsTpVeiculo = \'Cavalo Truck\'
                            AND (A.NrPlacaCarreta=B.NrPlaca OR A.NrPlacaReboque2=B.NrPlaca)
                            and A.DtBase = B.DtBase)  Then (select top 1 A.DsCarga from GTCLogist A
                                                            where A.DsTpVeiculo = \'Cavalo Truck\'
                                                            AND (A.NrPlacaCarreta=B.NrPlaca OR A.NrPlacaReboque2=B.NrPlaca)
                                                            and A.DtBase = B.DtBase)
        else B.DsCarga
    end as [DsCarga], 
        case when exists (select top 1 A.NrPlaca from GTCLogist A
                            where A.DsTpVeiculo = \'Cavalo Truck\'
                            AND (A.NrPlacaCarreta=B.NrPlaca OR A.NrPlacaReboque2=B.NrPlaca)
                            and A.DtBase = B.DtBase)  Then (select top 1 A.DtPrevChegDest from GTCLogist A
                                                            where A.DsTpVeiculo = \'Cavalo Truck\'
                                                            AND (A.NrPlacaCarreta=B.NrPlaca OR A.NrPlacaReboque2=B.NrPlaca)
                                                            and A.DtBase = B.DtBase)
        else B.DtPrevChegDest
    end as [DtPrevChegDest], 
        B.DtBase,
        B.DsObservacao,
        B.DsStatus
    from GTCLogist B
    where B.DsTpVeiculo like \'Carreta%\'
    and B.DtBase =  \''.self::convertData($obj->getdata()).'\' 
            and (exists (select top 1 H.NrPlaca from GTCLogist H
                            where H.DsTpVeiculo = \'Cavalo Truck\'
                            AND (H.NrPlacaCarreta=B.NrPlaca OR H.NrPlacaReboque2=B.NrPlaca)
                            and H.DtBase = B.DtBase
                            and H.DsDestino LIKE \''.$obj->getdest().'\')
        OR (NOT exists (select top 1 K.NrPlaca from GTCLogist K
                            where K.DsTpVeiculo = \'Cavalo Truck\'
                            AND (K.NrPlacaCarreta=B.NrPlaca OR K.NrPlacaReboque2=B.NrPlaca)
                            and K.DtBase = B.DtBase)
                            AND B.DsDestino LIKE \''.$obj->getdest().'\'))
    ');
     $stmt->execute();
        if($stmt) {
            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
                $prog = new Prog();
                $prog->setid($row->ID);
                $prog->setst($row->DsStatus);
                $prog->setplaca($row->NrPlaca);
                $prog->setcavalo($row->DsCavalo);
                $prog->setmot(stripslashes($row->DsMotorista));
                $prog->setsaida(date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row->DtSaida)));
                $prog->setorig($row->DsOrigem);
                $prog->setdest($row->DsDestino);
                $prog->setprev(date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row->DtPrevChegDest)));
                $prog->setcarga($row->DsCarga);
                $prog->setagen($row->DsAgendas);
                $prog->setobs($row->DsObservacao);
                $results[] = $prog;
            }
        }
    return $results;
}
```

Este SQL verifica na coluna Cavalo Truck se o cavalo possui alguma carreta, se sim ele trás todas informações dessa carreta se não possui nem uma carreta ele retorna em branco. Cada `else` é um select em cada coluna para trazer as informações se houver carreta. Isso falando a grosso modo.

Comment: Da um resumo do que ele faz, o que as tabelas são, etc. Vai ajudar a gente entender o que precisa retornar e tentar melhorar.

Comment: Qual é o banco?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kevin, sempre que vi uma consulta com uma `subquery` como campo do `select`, ela apresentava problemas de desempenho. No seu caso, você tem duas `subqueries` por campo.

Então tente mover as mesmas para o `LEFT JOIN` e use um `ISNULL`/`COALESCE` no lugar deste `case`:

```
WITH CTE_Cavalo AS (
    select 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY H.NrPlacaCarreta, H.NrPlacaReboque2 ORDER BY H.DtBase DESC) AS Ordem,
        H.NrPlacaCarreta,
        H.NrPlacaReboque2,
        H.NrPlaca,
        H.DtProg, 
        H.DsMotorista, 
        H.DtSaida, 
        H.HrSaida, 
        H.DtChegada, 
        H.HrChegada, 
        H.DsOrigem,
        H.DsDestino, 
        H.DsAgendas, 
        H.DsCarga, 
        H.DtPrevChegDest
    from GTCLogist H
    where 
        H.DsTpVeiculo = 'Cavalo Truck' AND 
        H.DtBase = @data AND
        H.DsDestino LIKE @dest 
), CTE_Todos AS (
    select 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY H.NrPlacaCarreta, H.NrPlacaReboque2 ORDER BY H.DtBase DESC) AS Ordem,
        H.NrPlacaCarreta,
        H.NrPlacaReboque2,
        H.NrPlaca
    from GTCLogist H
    where 
        H.DsTpVeiculo = 'Cavalo Truck' AND
        H.DtBase = @data
)

select 
    C.NrPlaca AS DsCavalo,
    B.ID,
    B.NrPlaca,
    ISNULL(C.DtProg, B.DtProg) AS DtProg,
    ISNULL(C.DsMotorista, B.DsMotorista) AS DsMotorista,
    ISNULL(C.DtSaida, B.DtPDtSaidarog) AS DtSaida,
    ISNULL(C.HrSaida, B.HrSaida) AS HrSaida,
    ISNULL(C.DtChegada, B.DtChegada) AS DtChegada,
    ISNULL(C.HrChegada, B.HrChegada) AS HrChegada,
    ISNULL(C.DsOrigem, B.DsOrigem) AS DsOrigem,
    ISNULL(C.DtPDsDestinorog, B.DDsDestinotProg) AS DsDestino,   
    ISNULL(C.DtPDsAgendasrog, B.DsAgendas) AS DsAgendas,
    ISNULL(C.DsCarga, B.DsCarga) AS DsCarga,
    ISNULL(C.DtPrevChegDest, B.DtPrevChegDest) AS DtPrevChegDest,
    B.DtBase,
    B.DsObservacao,
    B.DsStatus
from GTCLogist B
left join CTE_Cavalo AS C ON (C.NrPlacaCarreta = B.NrPlaca OR C.NrPlacaReboque2 = B.NrPlaca) and C.Ordem = 1
left join CTE_Todos AS D ON (D.NrPlacaCarreta = B.NrPlaca OR D.NrPlacaReboque2 = B.NrPlaca) and D.Ordem = 1
where 
    B.DsTpVeiculo like 'Carreta%' and 
    B.DtBase = @data and 
    B.DsDestino LIKE @dest and
    (C.NrPlaca IS NOT NULL OR D.NrPlaca IS NULL)
```

Comment: Tente novamente

Comment: @Kevin.F, este tipo de erro de sintaxe o `Manager Studio` pega na hora e é bastante simples de resolver, porém como eu não tenho a sua tabela, o mesmo não reconhece nenhuma coluna e não tem como eu analizar este tipo de cenario. Em todo caso, eu ja corrigi o erro de Sintaxe.